# Is it possible to style ::before of a checked checkbox's label?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a css injected ::before element of a label after the checkbox is selected.
Is it possible?
If it is how do I do it?

I have a checkbox and a label:

```
<div class="remember">
    <label for="remember-me" class="block">Remember Me</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
</div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this with css:

```
.remember input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before{
    content: '';
    background-color: #7b519d;
}
```

[I made a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aras_ir/38jhhaj0/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, in CSS, there is no [preceding-sibling](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) (or [parent](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)) selector; therefore we're unable to style the `<label>` based on the state (`:checked` or otherwise) of its subsequent `<input>` sibling. The posted CSS:

```
.remember input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before{
    content: '';
    background-color: #7b519d;
}
```

Will work only if the `<input>` element precedes the `<label>`:

```
<div class="remember">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
  <label for="remember-me" class="block">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

```css
/* Setting the defaults for the unchecked state: */
.remember input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.remember input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #7b519d;
}
```

```html
<div class="remember">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
  <label for="remember-me" class="block">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

Although you can use `float` to visually move the `<label>` before the `<input>`:

```
.remember input[type=checkbox] + label {
  float: left;
}
```

```css
.remember input[type=checkbox] + label {
  float: left;
}

.remember input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.remember input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #7b519d;
}
```

```html
<div class="remember">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
  <label for="remember-me" class="block">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

Or, depending on your cross-browser requirements, you could instead use flex-box and take advantage of the `order` property (and the various vendor-prefixed implementations) to position the elements correctly (`order: 1` for the `<label>` and `order: 2` for the `<input>`):

```css
.remember {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -moz-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.remember input:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.remember label:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.remember input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.remember input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #7b519d;
}
```

```html
<div class="remember">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
  <label for="remember-me" class="block">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

(Note that the above CSS for the flexbox demo was taken more or less in whole from the [the-echoplex.net's "Flexy Boxes" playground](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/).)

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](//www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
- [Attribute selectors](//www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- "[CSS Flexible Box Layout Module - Level 1](//www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)."
- [`float` ("Visual Formatting Model"](//www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).
- "[Using CSS Flexible boxes](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)."